# is there a way to access desktop audio on windows

Tags: windows, audio

im working on a windows app that needs to "hear" the desktop's audio, so the user runs it in the background and plays a game for example, the application would receive the sounds of that game, kind of like a screen recorder, but for audio only

Comment: Is this intended to be a programming question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: not directly a programming question i guess, more like asking for a library or something, i didnt know if there was a better website to ask though

Comment: i edited it, i hope its better now